# Change content depending on state

Tags: angular

So in Angular I can create a button doing something like this:

```
<a (click)="toggleState = !toggleState">Click me</a>
```

This I can then use to add/remove a class for some kind of div, e.g.:

```
<div [ngClass]="toggleState ? 'red-color' : 'green-color'">Some text</a>
```

with the CSS:

```
.red-color {
    color: red
}

.green-color {
    color: green
}
```

However, I am fairly new to Angular, so here's my question (since I know it can be done in React): Can I do something like this, where I actually change the content, and not just a class, e.g.:

```
{toggleState ?
    
    <div>Content one</div>
:

    <div>Content two</div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the [`ngIf` directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

```html
<div *ngIf="toggleState">Content one</div>
<div *ngIf="!toggleState">Content two</div>
```

You can create an else block more explicitly like such:

```html
<div *ngIf="toggleState; else elseBlock">Content one</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
  <div>Content two</div>
</ng-template>
```

If you're interested in learning more ways to change the DOM depending onr your component state, you can read more about structural directives [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives).

Answer (score 0):

You can also decouple angular `structural directives` from dom elements. Instead of slapping it on your div's you can put them on ng-containers. so

```
<ng-container *ngIf="foo"; else bar> ... <ng-container>
<ng-template #bar> ... <ng-template>
```

It's worth noting ng-template in something that only gets instantiated when it is referenced (as above, or ngTemplateOutlet). You can think of it as 'taking the place of what references it'

welcome to angular ~~~